# Ada : custom type in range 1..var?

Tags: ada

I'm a very beginner of Ada code. I use GPS from AdaCore.

I would create a variable sized by the user.
I write this :

```
-- My ada program --
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure main is
   wanted : Integer := 10;

   type custom is range 0..wanted;
...
```

But something went wrong in line 8 :

```
Builder results
    C:\Users\**********\Desktop\ada project\src\main.adb
        8:26 "wanted" is not static constant or named number (RM 4.9(5))
        8:26 non-static expression used for integer type bound
```

I really don't understand what this mean... Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `wanted` is not a constant, it may change its value during program execution, therefore this variable is not allowed to be used as range constraint when declaring new types. You may however make it constant by using `constant` keyword (`Wanted : constant Integer := 10;`). It should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As said by Timur, *wanted* has to be constant in its scope. This allows you some nice things such as declaring a type inside a procedure. Look at this, it might be of interest :)

```vhdl
-- My ada program --
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   procedure Test (Wanted : Integer) is
      type custom is new Integer range 0..wanted;
   begin
      Put_Line("First value " & Custom'Image (Custom'First) 
          & " Last value " & Custom'Image (Custom'Last));
   end Test;

begin
   Test (10);
   Test (12);
end Main;
```

Output is

```
First value  0 Last value  10
First value  0 Last value  12
```

In this case, your type is different from one call to another but it works as *wanted* is constant within the procedure. The only thing is that the type defined has to be a new derived type of the type of your parameter.

I let you think about the possibilities :)

Comment: Notice the difference between `type custom is range 0 .. wanted` and `type custom is new Integer range 0 .. wanted`.

Comment: Yes, of course, as _wanted_ is not constant, you have to create a derived type not a type, even though this is not easy to find why this is ok in the ARM :)